# Somebody has cleared my personal profile. Have they the right to do that?

Tags: support, profile-page

I received this message.

> https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/message/24#24 I'm writing in
>   reference to your Politics Stack Exchange account:
>
> https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/9704/little-alien
>
> Multiple users have complained about offensive language in your user
>   profile. Therefor I cleared it.
>
> Stack Exchange wants to maintain a professional and friendly
>   environment. If you decide to write another profile text, please
>   refrain from obscene language and aggression towards the rest of the
>   Stack Exchange community.
>
> Regards, Philipp Politics Stack Exchange moderator

because they do not share my political views. They make unethical step, I guess. I placed information about myself there. Which be nice do they want from me by attacking me?

Comment: Would it be possible to tell us what exactly was removed from your profile?

Comment: @Yannis http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Pj8fAgYrZtkJ:politics.stackexchange.com/users/9704/little-alien+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Comment: While I agree that what you wrote in your profile wasn't *that* offensive (yes, it was vulgar but vulgarity doesn't necessarily mean one isn't trying to make a point and just insulting others), I think the passages in the form of "You is a [insert swear word(s) here]" and point #4 aren't really appropriate even in one's profile.

Comment: The user profiles are the place with the fewest rules on SE sites. If you manage to break those, you might want to be careful on the sites in general. We have a bit higher standard of civility here, and on the actual SE sites we not only expect the absence of direct insults, but some professional behaviour in general.

Comment: @MadScientist 'Professional' here means to force your statement as granted truth, put blind eye on the arguments and not let anybody to qualify this behaviour.

Comment: Not everything is a political move - especially not this moderation.

Comment: Sure, if you do not take something for granted, if they ignore what you say and treat you like animal, which must be obedient and take everything they say as granted, it is pure question of civility to obey them. How can one be as stupid as me not to understand this?

Comment: @LittleAlien Be careful with your language on Stack Exchange. If you keep using those words, nothing good will come out of it.

Comment: @LittleAlien because what you are saying makes absolute zero sense? as a linked answer says the text in your about me sections was *"blatantly offensive and should be removed, as it is directed at "you" the reader of the profile (or possibly someone else, but it would normally be interpreted as the person reading)"* and your not really making any sort of argument to state otherwise so there's no arguments to put a blind eye on

Comment: @Memor-X Sure. I must obey. How cannot I understand? You ignore the portray of "you" that my profile was dedicated to, the qualities that I hate. You take "you" literally, as primitive animal. You are not trying to understand and use it as a justification to not try to understand anything.

Comment: Ah, calling people primitive animals......how cute.

Comment: @NZKshatriya No, the cute thing is to hide it. The nazi mindset 'We are great because these are we' is cute. Calling things their name is dull. Every George Carlin like me can do that. The dirty behaviour under respectable guise is cute. Go on.

Comment: @LittleAlien Reposting comments that moderators delete can land you in major trouble.  Also, comparing yourself to the great George Carlin is blasphemy.

Comment: You get a credit for twisting. 1. George Carlin was marxist (this is about telling the radical truth, non-conformism that makes you misanthropian rather than using the nice language to manipulate the audience in the interest of mainstream authority) 2. You is not my audience. Disregarding my message, twisting and using double standards, you prove over and over again that you is not my audience. Which micing of the words you ask from me? -40 downvotes for a legitimate question(s) does mean that nobody is against me.

Comment: @LittleAlien  39 downvotes mean that people are against your point of view, perhaps how you speak on this site.  One can disagree with someone and not hate that person.  You did not start yourself off on the right footing, by using swear words in your profile, no matter what the reason was for doing so.  Would you use that same language in a resume when applying for a job?  If I, or the collective I that is this site, is not your audience, then why are you espousing your views TO the collective "us?"  All that I can see is that you thrive on conflict.

Comment: Nobody hates anybody. People hate how and what person speaks. So, it is meaningless to say that somebody hates somebody. Wod−−youusetsˆamelangua≥∈are∑ewhenapply∈gforajob?Wod̲youusets^amelangua≥∈are∑ewhenapply∈gforajob?Would you use that same language in a resume when applying for a job? -- ask Carlin. His delivery makes no sense because no matter what this dirty mouth sais about his experience with humanity obviously cannot be applied for a job. Keep twisting. You get one more credit for saying that I must be sweet with you, obedient to your crazy quriks because you read me. Take my hard answ

Comment: Well, this has been........interesting.  You have a basic inability to answer simply questions posed to you, and you are more focused on arguing with everyone, and claiming that you are correct and everyone else is wrong/evil/nazi/whatever you want to call them at any given time.  I am done wasting energy on you.

Comment: Do not live so fast. I am prepared for more crap upon my head. You have displayed a good ability to do that and start was really promicing.

Answer (score 33):

Yes, site moderators and Stack Exchange employees have the right to reset user's details, which might be avatar, display name, About Me section in profile, etc.

That's part of keeping order in Stack Exchange and prevent people from being offended.

Judging from the message you quoted, it got nothing to do with political view and more with offensive language you've used in your profile.

I'll quote only a small part of what you wrote in there:

> You is a piece of bullshit

Is this a political view? No, it's not. I'm really glad the moderators removed it, and hope you will not keep insulting people with offensive language in the future.

Comment: Even here, you see that I am an alien. Every alien is an enemy for you. You downvote a normal question just because you consider me an enemy. You need to shut me up.

Comment: @LittleAlien It might be a good idea for you to step away from the computer for a few minutes and calm down.

Comment: @HDE226868 Do it.

Comment: @LittleAlien yes, you are indeed an alien. To Stack Exchange. You obviously fail to understand what is considered right, and what is considered wrong. Maybe offensive language and hate speech are accepted on your home planet, wherever it is, but not here.

Comment: @LittleAlien I'm going to repeat my warning. You're not making sense, you're spewing more obscenities, and you're clearly angry. Please do not keep randomly attacking people; I advise you to calm down.

Comment: Provoking anger is fine. Feeling angry is unacceptable. This is what you will never tell.

Answer (score 28):

While you are theoretically free to put anything you like in your profile you there are certain things that will get removed as soon as moderators (or employees) become aware of them. These include, but aren't limited to:

- Pornographic and other NSFW images
- Inappropriate user names
- Links to NSFW sites
- Hate speech
- Using a username/image to impersonate another user ("Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to [...] (c) create a false identity or to impersonate another person," - [source](https://stackexchange.com/legal))
- Using a username/image to harass another user("(b) harass, threaten, stalk or abuse any person or party, including other users of the Network," - ibid)

Stack Exchange sites are supposed to be professional places that people can use from their workplace. Content like this that makes it difficult (or indeed impossible) for people to use the sites will be removed.

Those with diamonds after their names - site moderators or employees with moderator powers - can do this. You will get a message about the why the offending content was removed. It is usually simpler for the moderator to completely remove the content rather than try to edit it.

Comment: @Raedwald I can't speak for all moderators or community managers, but I always send a message if I reset a user's profile. You'd have to raise an issue on the relevant meta or, probably better, use the "contact us" form to ask for an explanation.

Answer (score 17):

I am one of the multiple users who have complained about offensive language in your user profile. Here is the post, [Is offensive and rude language directed at you allowed in your profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286180/is-offensive-and-rude-language-directed-at-you-allowed-in-your-profile), that raised the issue about it.

One thing I want to advise you on is you can make yourself perfectly understood without using those words.

You can rewrite the profile page without those words. As explained by others, they can delete whatever they find unfit or inappropriate. But remember they tend to be very prudent before they decide to delete or edit out anything. That's for sure.

Comment: LittleAlien could totally use better English diction/grammar, because when he goes off on rants/swearing, it is so......off....that I cannot help but be more amused than offended.

Comment: @NZKshatriya Well, you will have a second thought when you read some of his posts.

Comment: Oh, I've read them lol, he's carrying out a mini-war higher up on this one lol.  I am apparently a nazi >.<  Also he has invaded the hardware recommendations stack, and cannot grasp scope lol.