# Why was my question edited wrongly?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

Yesterday I had asked a question on Stack Overflow about improving implementing logic or code, but users there changed my question. The title was changed to

> "How can I develop my knowledge so I could learn image recognition?"

When I had used "image recognition" only as an example. Why did they edit my question wrongly and without a suggested edit? I did edit the question today with exactly what I have to ask.

Comment: That user was trying to make [a very unclear, awfully broad question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386859/how-can-i-improve-implementing-code) at least a little bit readable. He did a good job.

Comment: I don't admit with it.  So he want I would have answers about image recognition. That's totally wrong. If they would edit with best I wouldn't mind otherwise to be happy more to supporting it.

Comment: They doing it consciously because couldn't get reputations and help at all. If they want to edit it then question must be remained what it is regarding otherwise violate question. Changing whole question meaning and purpose.

Comment: IMHO that was what you asked. Either way, it should be deleted, not edited.

Comment: @PatrickHofman  Thank you so much. Then delete it.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286217/somebody-has-cleared-my-personal-profile-have-they-right-to-do-that) question about profile editing. Your case is quite the same, just about posts. Users with edit privilege have full right to edit any post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40386859/1990216) was put on hold as "too broad". See [What is a "closed", “on hold”, or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question) The notice that was put on the question when it was put on hold reads:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

The user who edited your question was (I assume) trying to do exactly that, narrow the question down so that it could be reopened. Anyone with the  [edit privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (2000+ reputation) can edit questions and answers unilaterally. See [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) When a question is put on hold then edited (by you or anyone else) it is put in to a queue for people with sufficient reputation to decide whether it should be reopened or not.

Your subsequent edit again made it too broad and it is unlikely to be reopened as it is. Overly broad questions are not a good fit for Stack Exchange, they elicit overly long or incomplete answers and discussions—which is not what Stack Exchange is about. Try to narrow your questions down to a specific problem.

Comment: Ok then if I have to go with edited question will it help me really ? When it distracted what I want to know or what is problem I'm asking exactly. It'll give me lot of knowledge about image recognition instead core.

Comment: You can edit the question yourself, of course. If you're not interested specifically in image recognition then focus on something else, but asking how to "improve implementing code" is way way too broad a subject for a single question.

Comment: Thank you so much. You can see Ghostcat and JohnH comment there.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386859/how-can-i-improve-implementing-code?noredirect=1#comment68025895_40386859).