# Does the "Be Nice" policy apply when you are referring to a group of people, without naming names?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, be-nice-policy

**Edit regarding duplicate:** This question is not about SE users vs. people without an account on SE. Rather, it is about actual individuals that are named, vs. loosely defined groups of people defined by their views, ideas, etc. Thus, it does not matter whether this group consists of SE users or not, like in the question this one is now closed as a duplicate of.

---

This is related to a [post I made on meta Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4083/is-it-acceptable-to-refer-to-people-as-nutters-in-terms-of-the-be-nice-poli). All the relevant details of the particular case in question can be found in that post. This question is not, however, about that particular situation. It is more general in nature, and relates to the "Be Nice" policy.

A moderator referred to a group of people as "nutters". I flagged the comment, but it was declined. Normally, I believe calling someone a "nutter" would be a clear violation of the "Be Nice" policy, regardless of the views they held.

However, this situation is a bit different, as the user is not naming any given individual, but rather referring to a group of people who hold certain views, or propound certain ideas or arguments. Thus, I can see why some people would argue that this is not rude.

However, the user was clearly referring to *someone*. Thus, I personally tend to consider it rude.

This question is not about that particular situation, though.

**Does the “Be Nice” policy apply when you are referring to a group of people, without naming names?**

I would be interested in other people's views on this.

---

<sup>Related: [Does the Be Nice policy require SE users to "be nice" to people who are not SE users (e.g. public figures)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286082/does-the-be-nice-policy-require-se-users-to-be-nice-to-people-who-are-not-se-u)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure how that related question isn't exactly what your answer is here. The answer there could be pasted here with little editing and be the appropriate answer.

Comment: If you have a specific complaint about a declined flag, I recommend starting on Skeptics Meta, which you have. I think you should wait for a response there.

Comment: @Catija See my edit for my response. And I already posted on Skeptics meta, link is in this question :)

Comment: *I flagged the comment* ... which flag did you use? If you used a red flag (rude/abusive) you're using the wrong tool.

Comment: @rene Custom moderator flag, see details in linked question :)

Comment: I'm here, I read this question. I'm not going to visit another post to get the details I need to answer this.

Comment: @rene Alright, thanks. Though this question is a bit more about the general concept, not that particular situation.

Comment: The type of flags and if possible flag text are important then. It does matter what you ask the mod to do ....

Comment: @rene I mean this is about the "Be Nice" policy, not flags. I have edited for clarity, thanks.

Comment: The other question uses a specific example but the general concept "people who are not SE users" is the same.

Comment: @Catija Yeah, but it is talking about actual named individuals, which is a big difference.

Comment: No. Read the question without the e.g.

Comment: @Catija you could edit the group aspect easily in your answer there. Then I'm happy to dupe vote.

Comment: @rene Updated. Let me know if that's general enough.

Comment: @Catija it works for me, thanks.